# how save timer value in db in every minute automatic

Tags: javascript

javascript

```
    timedCount();

    function timedCount() {

        var hours = parseInt( c / 3600 ) % 24;
        var minutes = parseInt( c / 60 ) % 60;
        var seconds = c % 60;

        var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);


        $('#timer').html(result);
        if(c == 0 ){

    document.getElementById('submit_form').click();    
        }
        c = c - 1;
        t = setTimeout(function(){ timedCount() }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

how store timer value come from javascript automatic save  in database in every minute. please help i am in programming .

html

```
<h1 class="text-center text_underline"> Timer : <span id='timer'></span> </h1>
```

how store time value in database in every minute